# Getting access to Coq's rich XML-like AST output

Tags: coq

In older versions of Coq (< 8.5), the main *coqtop* process would interchange data with IDEs using strings.

This was supposedly recently changed - how does one query the richer XML-like structure representing ASTs?

Use case: I would like to interpret whatever Coq computes in a different way - that is, I need its results after performing operations (such as invoking tactics) in a form that's not string that I need to parse.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what your use case is? You can either use the XML protocol, (but that won't give you AST serialized data) or coq-serapi. By the way, I think older versions of Coq had very limited support for this xml plugin, but I am not sure now...

Comment: Note that your question is very specific about _querying the richer XML-like structure representing ASTs_ If what you want is to build a Coq IDE, then the answer would be a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

**Note: this answer has been edited to make it up to date**

The only reasonable option as of end of 2018 is [SerAPI](https://github.com/ejgallego/coq-serapi), a Coq language server that supports full serialization of Coq documents. Using SerAPI you can get a full representation of any Coq document or internal structure:

```
$ rlwrap sertop --printer=human
(Add () "Lemma u n : n + 0 = n.")
> (Answer 0 (StmAdded 2 (...) NewTip))
(Query ((sid 2)) Ast)
> (Answer 1(ObjList
>  ((CoqAst
>    (VernacStartTheoremProof Lemma
>     ((((((Id u)) ()))
>       (((LocalRawAssum
>          (((Name (Id n))))
>          (Default Explicit)
>          (CHole () IntroAnonymous ())))
>        (CNotation
>         "_ = _"
>         (((CNotation
>            "_ + _"
>            (((CRef
>               (Ident
>                 (Id n)))
>               ())
>              (CPrim
>               (Numeral (Ser_Bigint 0))))
>             () ()))
>           (CRef
>            (Ident
>              (Id n)))
>            ()))
>          () ()))
>        ())))
>     false)))))
```

Note that SerAPI is experimental software and I am the main author.

Comment: What is this `Annotate` thing part of?

Comment: It is a XML protocol call, see https://github.com/siegebell/vscoq/wiki/XML-protocol for more details. However be warned that it is far from complete and it will likely be removed.

Comment: Oh wow, I've been a googlin' for many a day now but I haven't stumbled upon the link you've mentioned. Thank you.

Comment: You still didn't explain what your use case is, so it may be difficult to give a more accurate answer.

Comment: So you have two choices then: to use the XML protocol, which has known pitfalls, but it is more stable, or use SerAPI, which will make your life easier in many ways, but will change soon to make your life as an IDE developer even easier, so you will have to adapt. It is thus your call, but the specification for the SerAPI protocol should be online soon.

Comment: @ejgallego: The XML protocol will likely be removed?! But people are building new IDEs around it right now!

Comment: PS: you could have included a disclaimer that you are the author of SerAPI.

Comment: The _XML printer call_ will be likely removed, not the protocol. About the printer: it is useless in its current state and it is looking like nobody is looking forward to fix it. Regarding the disclaimer, yeah I am one of the authors, but I fail to see what I have to "disclaim" sorry. For now, SerAPI just exposes what Coq exposes.